# JMockit is not instantiating captured interfaces in Expectations block

Tags: java, junit, mocking, jmockit, expectations

I'm not sure whether I'm using JMockit incorrectly, or there's something amiss in my setup.  I'm using JMockit 1.32 with JUnit 4.12 in Eclipse.

My problem seems to be that interfaces aren't being captured.  Specifically in the `java.sql` package.  For example:

```
public class Dto {
    private int id;

    public Dto(){}

    public Dto(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            id = rs.getInt(1);
        } catch (SQLException e) { }
    }

    public int getId() {return id;}
    void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
}
```

.

```
public class ClassUnderTest {
    public static Dto loadObject(Connection conn, String tablename, int id) {
        Dto result = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {
            String sql = "select * from " + tablename + " where id = ?";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, id);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                result = new Dto(rs);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {  
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ps != null) ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) { }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class ResultSetTest  extends junit.framework.TestCase {

    private static final int OBJ_ID = 5;

    @Capturing
    ResultSet mockResultSet;

    @Capturing
    PreparedStatement mockStatement;

    @Capturing
    Connection mockConn;



    @Test
    public void testGetDtoById() throws SQLException {

        new Expectations() {{
            mockConn.prepareStatement(anyString);  result = mockStatement;
            mockStatement.setInt(anyInt, OBJ_ID);
            mockResultSet.next();                  result = true;
            new Dto(mockResultSet);                result = new Dto();
            mockResultSet.next();                  result = true;
        }};

        Dto dto = ClassUnderTest.loadObject(mockConn, "", OBJ_ID);

        assertEquals(dto.getId(), OBJ_ID);    
    }
}
```

In this setup, test execution fails with a NPE on the first line in the `Expectations(){}` block.  But from the tutorials, etc. I'm expecting a mocked instance to have been created. ([e.g. tutorial](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#mockingUnspecifiedImplementations))

Trying to move past this, I created explicit mocked classes like so:

```
public class ResultSetMockup extends MockUp<ResultSet> { }

public class PreparedStatementMockup extends MockUp<PreparedStatement>
{    
    @Mock ResultSet executeQuery() {return new ResultSetMockup().getMockInstance();}
}

public class ConnectionMockup extends MockUp<Connection> 
{
    @Mock PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) throws SQLException { 
        return new PreparedStatementMockup().getMockInstance(); 
    }
}

@Capturing
ResultSet mockResultSet = new ResultSetMockup().getMockInstance();

@Capturing
PreparedStatement mockStatement = new PreparedStatementMockup().getMockInstance();

@Capturing
Connection mockConn = new ConnectionMockup().getMockInstance();
```

At this point, the `Expectations() {}` block is happy, but it appears that `results` is never actually being set.  By setting a breakpoint I see that `rs.next()` always fails.  So I presume nothing is actually being captured.

What am I doing wrong?  Or is something in my setup preventing JMockit from actually running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem in the test is that it's mixing the APIs from JUnit 3 (anything from `junit.framework`) and JUnit 4+ (`org.junit`). This should never be done.

JMockit only supports the JUnit 4 API, not the obsolete JUnit 3 API. So, simply remove "`extends from junit.framework.TestCase`" that it will be ok.

BTW, your Java IDE should have warned against this mistake. IntelliJ, at least, promptly displays "Method 'testGetDtoById()' annotated with '@Test' inside class extending JUnit 3 TestCase".

Also, the test (and the code under test) has several other mistakes...

Comment: Thanks, Rogério.  I'm marking this as the answer because it answered the original question.  I would never have known about the mixed APIs.  Eclipse said nothing, and I'd just imported the current sdk from junit.  As for the "other mistakes"  I've learned that the two `mockResetSet.next()` calls won't work as is and should instead be a single call with `returns(true, false);`.  Anything else of significance? In my actual code I've switched to testng and gotten most everything working.  But I still had trouble combining @Capturing with mocking specific methods.  I'm guessing that's a no-no?

Comment: @Didjit In `ClassUnderTest`, I only see *one* call to `rs.next()`, so there is no need to record two return values for it. Other things: 1) the test will need to record the `rs.getInt(1)` call, or it will return zero; 2) `Dto` is not mocked, so that expectation on the constructor doesn't make sense; 3) expectations on `prepareStatement` and `setInt` are not really needed; 4) not a good idea to swallow `SQLException`'s - instead wrap them in `new RuntimeException(e)`.

Comment: All good feedback, @Rogério. Thanks!  So then, `Dto` would have to be explicitly mocked in order to intercept the constructor? I.e. that doesn't happen automatically?  And I included `prepareStatement` so that it would return a (mocked) object instead of null. Am I missing something here?  `setInt()` was meant as a test, but I think I'd have to add `times = 1` for it to be of any use, is that right?  I really like the idea and power of your framework, but I confess it's been a challenge to learn how to use it effectively. (Oh, and the exceptions -- that was just to keep the code clean. :-D )

Comment: A mocked `PreparedStatement` will be returned automatically from `mockConn`, due to cascaded mocking (which is always active). Same with the `ResultSet`. `Dto` shouldn't be mocked in this case (or ever, since it's a "value object" and such objects generally aren't mocked).

Answer (score 0):

My problem appears to have been the use of JUnit. I went as far as to try tutorial examples verbatim without luck.  But by converting over to TestNG all my problems went away.

It seems as though JMockit's Expectations block wasn't able to hook into the code properly with JUnit.  Either calls weren't recognized or the faking wasn't happening.  I'm curious now, does anyone have it working with JUnit?